# How can I modify field value after Drupal webform sumission

Tags: php, email, drupal, drupal-webform

I'm trying to modify value of the submitted field with php (server-side) to be send by mail and written to db:

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
```

changing of value looks easy, but nothing happens after I change it. Hook works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hook_form_alter` only manipulates the form **before** it gets rendered:

> Perform alterations before a form is
>   rendered.

Have a look at [this API comment](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6#comment-2118), where someone gives a nice example of how to do something after the form has been submitted. There is also a `_submit($form, &$form_state)` action (the given post from the link points that out) that you need to trigger. You can do all your needed altering there. A little bit more description can be found in the [examples](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/example_form_submit/6) from the API

Answer (score 0):

```
First add a submit action in hook_form_alter and second alter the form_state value in form     submission. 

function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'your-webform-id') {
      $form['#submit'][] = 'xyz_form_submit';
    }
}

function xyz_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
// here you can edit $form_state value before final submit

}
```